# Bot waiting for the other bot's response before sending another message. (Discord.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I created a bot that responses to another bot; somehow related to Cleverbot. However, when the bot takes time to respond, its message gets stuck and it spams. I'm just wondering, how I can make the bot wait for the message of the other bot to send before it sends a message again. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5yLt.jpg)

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  if(!message.author.bot) return
  message.channel.startTyping();
  let content = message.content;
  chatbot.getReply(content).then(r => message.channel.send(r))
  message.channel.stopTyping();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do that on the **stable** version of Discord.js(v12)

```
...

client.on('message', async message => {

var author = message.author;
var content = message.content;
var botChannel = message.channel;

if(author.bot){
//author is a bot so we respond
botChannel.startTyping();
botChannel.send(`${author}, <Your message here>`).then( (msg) => {
      botChannel.stopTyping();
  }
 );
} else {
    //nothing happens because it's a human 
    return; 
}
);
```

Comment: I tried the code that you provided for me, however, it only shows that the bot is typing and not sending any messages. If it's ok, you can contact me on Discord: Cult#9156

Comment: I tried the updated code and substitute `<Your message here>` to `Test` but both bots just spammed the message with me mentioned and the `Test` message. Therefore, I changed `Test` to `content` and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Jhay well i wasn't aware of the behavior of the other bot as it wasn't defined in your question. If the other bot responds when this one types a message, yes, they will both spam each other; much like an infinite loop. If that's what you want, but you don't want them to spam.. check out the ```setTimeout()``` function and maybe put it below ```botChannel.startTyping()``` in my code.